# How can I retrieve a message as an object from a JSON object in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, json, object, npm, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot and I'm currently working on an election feature for the moderator of my server.
I'm saving all the data needed for the election in an external `JSON` file, so that, if the bot breaks during an election, it can resume from where it left off without user input when it restarts (I'm using the npm package [`edit-json-file`](https://npmjs.com/package/edit-json-file) in order to edit and read my `JSON`).

The problem is that when I retrieve a message object (for which I want to create a reaction collector) from the `JSON`, I get this error:

```
TypeError: electionData.get("message").createReactionCollector is not a function
```

The message object in my `JSON` looks like this:

```
{
  "message": {
    "channelID": "678347518907777062",
    "deleted": false,
    "id": "750965454297628754",
    "type": "DEFAULT",
    "content": "@everyone",
    "authorID": "729286679822860309",
    "pinned": false,
    "tts": false,
    "system": false,
    "embeds": [
      {
        "type": "rich",
        "title": "Election",
        "description": "It's time to vote! \n\n for <@247283454440374274> \n for <@235088799074484224> \n\n__*Warning:*__ *You* ***can't*** *remove or change your vote later.*",
        "color": 15046144,
        "timestamp": 1599114577345,
        "fields": [],
        "thumbnail": null,
        "image": null,
        "video": null,
        "author": null,
        "provider": null,
        "files": []
      }
    ],
    "attachments": [],
    "createdTimestamp": 1599114516568,
    "editedTimestamp": null,
    "webhookID": null,
    "applicationID": null,
    "activity": null,
    "flags": 0,
    "reference": null,
    "guildID": "591947002066108424",
    "cleanContent": "@everyone"
  }
}
```

I also tried to cache the message by its id but I just couldn't...
What can I do to retrieve the message as an object from the `JSON`?

Comment: How is `electionData` created?

Comment: do you want to send a message use emoticons for vote?

Comment: `electionData.message` should work.

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava exactly, but I want to be able to reuse the message object later from an external source

Comment: @ChrisG I created it via that same npm package

Comment: @mtx it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you read JSON it'll return a plain object, with just properties filled in. You're trying to call a method as if `electionData.get("message")` is a class.

So you either need to instantiate a new class with your JSON data, or move the function outside of the class.

Comment: I didn't quite understand that 2nd part

Comment: nevermind... instead of `electionData.get("message").createReactionCollector(...);` I made a new object from it and it works, thanks